# Converting a chi2 to a sigma value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, astronomy

I am working in astronomy. I fit a theoretical model to some data. The model takes input parameters (like the mass and age) and produces some outputs that I compare with the data.

I measured the goodness of fit of the model

$$\chi^2 = \frac{1}{N-P}\sum_i^N \left( \frac{\mu_i - y_i}{\sigma_i} \right)^2$$

where $N$ is the number of measurements, $P$ is the number of input parameters to my model, $\mu$ are the measurements, $\sigma$ are their estimated 1-standard-deviation uncertainties of the measurements, and $y$ are the values of my model. A value of $\chi^2 = 1$ is a good match.

I then add some physics to my model,  and calculate a value of $\chi^2$ for that. I find that the first model has a $\chi^2$ of 9, whereas my new model has a $\chi^2$ of 4.

Can this be translated into a $\sigma$, e.g., could one say that this is a $5\sigma$ effect?

Comment: A "so-many-sigma" effect would - assuming I understand it right - be related to some change in an estimate of some unknown quantity; e.g $|\hat{\theta}_1-\hat{\theta}_0|$ compared to some estimated or otherwise derived standard error of that estimate; their ratio would be the "sigma-number". I don't see (perhaps from ignorance of the physics) enough information here to figure out how to see what that might be in this situation.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your comment. I think the situation you describe is similar to mine. The physics I've added to the model has a new parameter $\theta$; the model without this physics is just $\theta=0$. I calibrate the $\theta$ to the data; the model now performs better with $\theta>0$, but I want to quantify how much better (in terms of sigma).

Comment: @Glen_b I guess the right way to tackle this problem is to measure $\chi^2(\theta)$ across a range of values for $\theta$. Then I can get sigma from dividing the value at the optimum by the standard deviation of the resulting distribution. However, it's not clear to me how to get the standard deviation if $\chi^2>1$ for all values of $\theta$.